# change range of the kinect depth camera

Tags: kinect, depth

How range is the depth camera in the kinect and can I change it?

I want to change range of depth data. Currently ı can receive and process data. I did some research on this subject, but I could not reach a conclusion.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Kinect itself has limitations. If you are looking for tracking more than it can according to the wiki it says "The Kinect sensor has a practical ranging limit of 1.2–3.5 m (3.9–11.5 ft) distance when used with the Xbox software". Also I don't think you can change the capability of the device (In hardware level). So if you are looking for a sub range of this it is possible but if the range is far from this its impossible.If you are looking for a range then you can limit the Z values upon certain threshold like..

```
if(yourClosestRange < kinectRealZ < yourFarmostRange)
```

{

```
int zInRange = kinectRealZ;
```

}

hope you could understand my point.